# Understanding Type Classes, Scala implicit and C#

Tags: c#, scala, haskell, functional-programming

I read this blog post by [Joe Duffy](http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/02/28/on-haskell-type-classes-and-c-interfaces/) about Haskell type classes and C# interfaces.

I'm trying to understand what could have enabled c# to have type classes,
and I wonder whether a feature like scala's ***implicits*** could solve it?

having this kind of feature would enable writing something like this:

```
public interface IReducableOf<T>
{
   T Append(T a, T b);
   T Empty();
}

public T Reduce(this IEnumerable<T> vals, **implicit** IReducerOf<T> reducer )
{
  Enumerable.Aggregate(vals, reducer.Append);
}
```

making sure that we have in our context an implementation of `IReducerOf<T>`
than the compiler could "just" pick the reducer and use it to execute the code.

of course, this code cannot compile.

But my questions are:

1. Can this enable implementing type classes?
2. Is this similar to what is happening in scala?

I'm asking this for general understanding and not for a particular problem.

**UPDATE**

I've encountered this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/CaptainHayashi/roslyn/blob/master/concepts/docs/concepts.md) on possible implementation of type classes in c#

Comment: Yes. `implicit` is how Scala does type classes. The main difference is that `implicit` works by looking for values in scope, whereas classes work with a global database of unique instances

Comment: When you say classes you mean haskell's type classes? so in compilation haskell searches the global instances db to find a matching instance?)

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Implicits are very, very similar to type classes. Probably the only key difference is that you can, IIRC, pass the implicit argument is you so desire, when using typeclasses (at least in Haskell) you can not. I think in Scala you can have two, but then (of course) the compiler can not chose the implicit automatically for you, yet you can pass it explicitly (I think). In Agda implicits work in that way: if you have only one value in scope, that's it, otherwise you have to be explicit to disambiguate.

Comment: Implicits enable type classes, but (in my opinion) higher kinded types would be required to make them most useful.

Comment: @chi: Scala does have a search priority for implicits, so you can have higher-priority implicits override lower-priority ones, but you cannot have more than one applicable implicit. That's an error. However, as you mentioned, you can simply pass an explicit argument for an implicit parameter, in which case implicit search isn't even attempted and thus there won't be an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly how type classes are implemented in Scala. It is a general design principle in Scala to add general and re-usable features to the language that can be used to implement higher-level constructs as library constructs, if at all possible. In this particular case, type classes can be implemented using objects and implicits, but both objects and implicits have uses beyond merely implementing type classes, so it makes more sense to include those more general building blocks in the language and allow the users to build higher-level constructs (like type classes) on top.

The canonical paper on implementing type classes as objects and implicits is the aptly named [*Type Classes as Objects and Implicits* by Bruno C. d. S. Oliveira, Adriaan Moors, and Martin Odersky](http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~bruno/papers/TypeClasses.pdf). There's a nice [discussion of this paper on Lambda-the-Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4039).

Note that just adding implicits to the language would probably not be enough. You could implement type classes that way, but a lot of "interesting" type classes (such as `Monad`) cannot be expresses in C♯: `Monad` is higher-kinded, but C♯'s type system is not.